# Django 4 Проверить добавлена ли статья в закладки

Tags: python, django, django-model

Не могу реализовать условие, которое проверяет добавлена ли статья в закладки пользователем.  Нужно сделать так, что если статья добавлена показывалась ссылка на удаление из закладок, иначе показывалась бы ссылка на добавление в закладки.

Модель для закладок:

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Шаблон:

```
   {% if post.is_bookmarked %}
    <a href="#">Удалить статью</a> 
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'add_bookmark' post.id %}"></a>
{% endif %}
```

simple_tag:

```
from django import template

from app_name.models import Bookmark

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name='is_bookmarked')
def is_bookmarked(post, request):
    try:
        user_bookmark = Bookmark.objects.get(user=request.user, article=post)
        if user_bookmark:
            return True
    except:
        pass
    return False
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так...